# Are vitual machine recommendations on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I need a few Linux virtual machines (Oracle VirtualBox .VDI), for various software  development environments, all using only free software, so no copyright/piracy issues.

I ***could*** just make them myself, but am afflicted by congenial(*) laziness, and someone out there almost certainly has made them, as I am thinking of fairly standard development setups.

The thing is, I am unsure if virtual machines are actually apps. Sure, they ***contain*** apps, but they can be seen as being data for the VirtualBox app.

I am probably worrying needlessly, but thought that I would ask here before posting such a request. What's your verdict?

Btw, I am aware of the [Vee Dee Eyes](https://virtualboximages.com/veedeeeyes/vdi/index) site, but it doesn't offer what I want (which is strange, as it is a common request), and, in any case, I would like a clear ruling as to whether such requests are on topic here.

---

(*) no, I don't mean congenital; I'm just happy to be lazy :-)

Comment: Not answering this but adding a pointer: Some VMs are called "virtual appliances" – which comes close to "applications" IMHO: a software tool to serve a purpose. So if you're talking VM in this context, it should fit. But let's see what other members of our community have to say on that :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We already have such a question, written by the laziest member of our community:

[VM image distribution of a Kerberos server?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/248/vm-image-distribution-of-a-kerberos-server)

It seems that this question has been well received, with 8 upvotes.

As long you describe your requirements:

- Exact purpose of the VM (something specific)
- VM software it should run of (or just say that any is fine)
- Budget

it is on-topic.

Comment: Since that is what I wanted to here, I will award it the answer. Btw, that question (now) has 9 upvotes :-)

Comment: P.s do you have any idea about https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/48001/app-to-build-a-virtual-box-vdi-virtual-machine-for-ubuntu ?

Comment: @Mawg make it 10!